# How to show particular Text Lines in Italic format in the TextArea Tag in SAP Fiori Apps?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sapui5, sap-fiori

I want to show **particular text-lines** in the "TextArea" tag in *italic* format in **SAP Fiori App**.
 
My text-area data is coming from **SAP OData Service** in the form of Array. I am able to display the data by using for loop & then set my final data as below (**JS** sample code):-

```
var tempcomm = this.getView().byId("txtArea"); 
oModel.setData({
                text_listSet : data   //here data - contains the final data
            }); 
tempcomm.setModel(oModel);
```

Below is the **XML View** sample code:-

```
<TextArea id="txtArea" 
                        value="{/text_listSet}"
                        height="20rem" growing="true" editable="false" />
```

Current o/p:- 
 
test Line 1.
 
ok, good - line 2. 

 
test Line 3.
 
ok, good - line 4.

Desired o/p:- 
 
*test Line 1- italic format.*
 
ok, good - line 2. 

 
*test Line 3 - italic format.*
 
ok, good - line 4.

**Note:-** Text Area is **non-editable**.

Comment: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.m.FormattedText

Answer (score 1):

If sapui5 uses the normal HTML 5 textarea, then there is no way to format text inside it. If you want to be able to format text, then you will have to create your own custom element with `contenteditable="true"` then populate it with `<i></i>` tags or `<span></span>` tags with `font-style:` changes in css.

See docs for `contenteditable`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable